# Extract response data array from fetch function with post method

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I've written an async function which is able to get a response from an API I've written in Python but I can't get the data into an array which I can then use to update my frontend application.

The code is as follows:

```
async function postData(URL) {
  let rawResponse = await fetch(URL, {
    method: "Post",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(inputData),
  });
  const data = await rawResponse.json();
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}  

let response1 = postData();
console.log(response1);

let response2 = postData()["returnedData"];
console.log(response2);
```

The code returns the array I want when I console.log the data variable within the function.  However, it returns an array called 'Promise{pending}'* for response1 which contains the desired data but I am not able to manipulate it and returns 'undefined' for response2.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

*pending even though the PromiseState is 'fulfilled'

Answer (score 2):

PostData Function is a [aync Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) so returns a Promise so you must use await before calling it or .then

```js
async function postData(URL) {
  let rawResponse = await fetch(URL, {
    method: "Post",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(inputData),
  });
  const data = await rawResponse.json();
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}
// Method 1
const init = async () => {
  let response1 = await postData();
  console.log(response1);

  let response2 = await postData()["returnedData"];
  console.log(response2);
}
init();
// Method 2
(async () => {
  let response1 = await postData();
  console.log(response1);

  let response2 = await postData()["returnedData"];
  console.log(response2);
})()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  What do I need to do to be able to manipulate the responses outside of a function?

Comment: What you can do is  to declare a let variable outside **init function** and reassign it in the **init function**

Comment: When I use this code I still got a promise showing in the console window: const init = async () => {
  let data = await postData();
  return data;
};

let data = init();
console.log(data);

Comment: Yes Becoz init is async function
**Try This**
let data; 
const init = async () => { 
data = await postData(); 
return data; 
};
init();
console.log(data)

Comment: The data variable is still showing as a promise using this method unfortunately

Comment: Yeah I Tested it sry you need to wrap all your js code like `Method 2` or a init function **Example** [Codepen](https://codepen.io/vakhariaheet/pen/ZErOxgq?editors=1111)